# QuickSort example in Erlang

Tags: erlang

I have a question about an Erlang QuickSort implementation:

```
qsort([]) -> [];
qsort([Pivot|T]) -> qsort([X || X <- T, X < Pivot]) ++ [Pivot] ++ qsort([X || X <- T, X >= Pivot]).
```

The code above is from a book named *Erlang Programming*, and I don't understand why the second function has a code snippet `X >= Pivot`. Why `>=` but not `>` when there is already `++[Pivot]++` in the middle of this section of the function?

Comment: Thanks for your help @dethron5000

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[Pivot]` basically puts the single element `Pivot` into a list for the purpose of concatenating with the other 2 lists. It doesn't account for other elements with the same value in your input. Therefore, you need to handle it in either the left or right side of your implementation to ensure that such values are not left out when returning the sorted list.

e.g. Let's say your input list is [5,3,6,5,2,7]. There are three sublists that you need to deal with:

1. [Pivot] = [5]
2. [X || X <- T, X < Pivot] = [3,2]
3. [X || X <- T, X > Pivot] = [6,7]

But what about the second "5" in your input? It doesn't figure in any of the above sublists, so when you combine them to get the sorted list out, it's not there any more! Now, if you were to modify either sublist 2 or 3 to check for equality as well, you would get new sublists [3,2,5] or [6,5,7], making sure that all elements in input are considered. Note that it is symmetrical, so you can use "<=" in the left side instead of ">=" in the right side as in your example.